# how to remove legends from MS chart in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-visualization

I am trying to remove or disable the legend from MS chart but i can't seem to find where and how to remove the legends

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var options = {
                title: 'Total Hours By Project Category',
                is3D: true

            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Home.aspx/GetChartData",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($("#chart")[0]);
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                },
                failure: function (r) {
                    alert(r.d);
                },
                error: function (r) {
                    alert(r.d);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

in aspx

```
   <div id="chart" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; "> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var options = {
          legend: 'none'
        };
```

See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart?csw=1#Configuration_Options

Comment: Great--glad I could help!  Please accept it as the answer.